# Get hierarchical nested data from MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I am new in MongoDB. But, I have the understanding of some [aggregate](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/) functions/operators.

First, please have a look at the data (it contains cricket matches information):

One document(row) looks like this:

```
{
    "ID": 577,
    "Inning": 1,
    "BattingTeam": "Sunrisers Hyderabad",
    "BowlingTeam": "Royal Challengers Bangalore",
    "Over": 1,
    "Bowler": "S Aravind",
    "Ball": 1,
    "Batsman": "DA Warner",
    "NonStriker": "S Dhawan",
    "TotalRuns": 1
}
...
...
```

Here is the whole data file:
http://raw.sam016.com/shared/match_data.json

Those who don't know cricket (like me), here is little info:

- A match contains 2 innings [1, 2]
- Each inning contains some overs [20, 60]
- Each over contains 6 balls max

I want to aggregate/group this data in such a way to get the following kind of hierarchical result:

```
[{
    "ID": 577,
    "Innings": [{
            "Inning": 1,
            "BattingTeam": "Sunrisers Hyderabad",
            "BowlingTeam": "Royal Challengers Bangalore",
            "Overs": [
                {
                    "Over": 1,
                    "Bowler": "S Aravind",
                    "Balls": [
                        {
                            "Ball": 1,
                            "Batsman": "DA Warner",
                            "NonStriker": "S Dhawan",
                            "TotalRuns": 1
                        },
                        {...},
                        {...}
                    ]
                },
                {...},
                {...}
            ]
        },
        {
            "Inning": 2,
            "BattingTeam": "Royal Challengers Bangalore",
            "BowlingTeam": "Sunrisers Hyderabad",
            "Overs": [
                {
                    "Over": 1,
                    "Bowler": "B Kumar",
                    "Balls": [
                        {
                            "Ball": 1,
                            "Batsman": "CH Gayle",
                            "NonStriker": "V Kohli",
                            "TotalRuns": 0
                        },
                        {...},
                        {...}
                    ]
                },
                {...},
                {...}
            ]
        }
    ]
}]
```

Any kind of help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try below aggregation pipeline.

You just `$group` on key and `$push` the data to create each level.

Start with innermost level `Balls` and work your way up to the `Innings`.

```
db.cricket.aggregate({
    $group: {
        "_id": {
            "ID": "$ID",
            "Inning": "$Inning",
            "BattingTeam": "$BattingTeam",
            "BowlingTeam": "$BowlingTeam",
            "Over": "$Over",
            "Bowler": "$Bowler"
        },
        "Balls": {
            $push: {
                "Ball": "$Ball",
                "Batsman": "DA Warner",
                "NonStriker": "S Dhawan",
                "TotalRuns": "$TotalRuns"
            }
        }
    }
},
{
    $group: {
        _id: {
            "ID": "$_id.ID",
            "Inning": "$_id.Inning",
            "BattingTeam": "$_id.BattingTeam",
            "BowlingTeam": "$_id.BowlingTeam"
        },
        "Overs": {
            $push: {
                "Over": "$_id.Over",
                "Bowler": "$_id.Bowler",
                "Balls":"$Balls"
            }
        }
    }
},
{
    $group: {
        "_id": "$_id.ID",
        "Innings": {
            $push: {
                "Inning": "$_id.Inning",
                "BattingTeam": "$_id.BattingTeam",
                "BowlingTeam": "$_id.BowlingTeam",
                "Overs":"$Overs"
            }
        }
    }
})
```

Comment: How to have it sorted? I have tried adding `$sort` by inning>over>ball. But the final result is not sorted.

Comment: You have to sort one level at a time. So for first level you'll need `$sort` by ball before pushing. Something like `{$sort:{Ball:1}}` before first $group and so on for rest of the levels.

Comment: I am doing `$sort` by `$_id` before each `$group`. Sorting by `$_id`, would it affect the performance by some way?